# Rails : ip addresses of subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ip, subdomain, local

Say I usually make requests to my app using the local network ip address `192.168.1.26`

I now have a new subdomain. How do I find the local network ip address of this new subdomain ?
With the Rails console or with a command line, either is good.

Answer (score 0):

Add subdomain.example.com to your /etc/hosts file, pointing to the IP address.

example:

`172.16.31.196   devwork   subdomain.example.com`

Then you can just type the subdomain.example.com in your url and you'll get what you want.

Comment: I don't see how. I still don't know the ip address associated with my subdomain. What you're suggesting is the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Your subdomain will normally not have it's own IP address, it will be the same as your localhost (unless you've set it up to have its own ip address)... however you can access it via the example I gave you.

Comment: devwork is just an alias I have on my own system, that way I can just type in devwork and it's an alias to the ip address above. I can also do `ping devwork` and it will ping that ip address. It's not relevant to our example, you can remove it or put whatever else you want.